# What do you call a film shot that let us see the 3/4 of people's body on the foreground?

Tags: word-request

Is there a name for it? Sometimes in films we see most of the body of the main characters talking except maybe the legs. I am wondering if there's a particular word to describe these movie "shots" if we can call them that.

Comment: Perhaps, but it would be a technical term in cinematography, rather than a general English word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is called either the "Medium Wide Shot", the "Cowboy Shot", or the "Medium shot", depending on how much of the legs are shown..  As James K mentions, these are *jargon*, and not in general use by everyday English speakers -- meaning the average person would have no idea what you mean.

More info for you:  [The Ultimate Guide to Camera Shots (over 50+ Types of Shots and Angles in Film)](https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/ultimate-guide-to-camera-shots/).  See Section 1 for the names of various shot sizes.